# set up mailserver for multiple domains guide for beginner

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, dns, postfix

I am not Linux pro, and after days of trying with tutorials how to set up postfix or other e-mail server I am try to find solution here.

In your office we have HP Proliant server with Ubuntu server 12.10. I installed configured, the `mysql`, `apache2`, `php5`, `vnc`, `ssh`, to provide webhosting for our clients (we do not provide DNS service). I tested it on multiple domains and subdomains everything is fine.
Now I want to set up email server for our domain and for any other domain pointing to our ip adress. So if we create website for you client, we provide him and domain **example.com** with webhosting and also we want to provide him a email addresses like **something@example.com**.

I red some tutorials with postfix + mysql for vitual users but lot of config files are in other location or main file is including others. So I cant find lot of things in included files and main file that tutorials is described. (They seems to be outdated)

Can somebody provide me step by step instructions or ebook how to set up mailserver? From `apt-get install` to fetch messages with email client.

in short:

1. not virtualized
2. we do not provide dns service (We are using A record on domains)
3. test domain is from http://dot.tk  (soft-tech-srv.tk) using Dot.TK Free DNS service
4. System is Ubuntu server 12.10 amd64, with Xfcedesktop and SSH + VNC access
5. MySQL, Apache2, PHP5, FTP installed and configured
6. full email service is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on running your web services and email on the same Ubuntu server? If so I would advise against it. If you have a spare server to dedicate to your email service then I would recommend using Zimbra - http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/os-downloads.html . You can also make use of Exim - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Exim4

Comment: thank yout, i will try zimbra, now i am trying with http://www.iredmail.org/

Comment: I would recommend reading the excellent [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html), especially the [Virtual Domain Hosting HOWTO](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html). From my point of view giving a complete tutorial is way too much. Because there are lots of special cases, pitfalls etc. It would be better if you try to set it up and ask specific questions which come up during the process.

Comment: Here full details are gives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixCompleteVirtualMailSystemHowto It include, multi-domain, email server configuration, database configuration. Follow step by step and install full multi-domain enabled email server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial on [www.howtoforge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.10) works perfectly to install postfix with courier and mysql for your situation using virtual users (so you don't need to open a Linux account for every mail user).

The config files used are on the default places if you install with `apt-get`. It is long  but basically it installs everything using `apt-get`, build the mysql queries to manage virtual users and mails (6 simple queries if remember well) and configure postfix main and master config files. You also install squirrelmail as webmail software.

Comment: howtoforge tutorial not worked for me :-( postfix is not listening on 25, on restart or start i get warnings: unused parameters in main.cf and master.cf... can connect form telnet but not welcome message and cant use quit command, also port 25 seems to be blocked by isp.

Comment: You should change postfix master.cf to listen on 587 (subscription port) which is the recomended now (25 is blocked in most ISP and mail servers). The unused parameters warning is no problem, postfix works without problem with these warnings. They are issued due to a postfix bug I think.

Comment: sorry for late reply it worked :-) we asked isp to unblock the 25 port.

Comment: before trying to follow all those steps, do you know if the newer versions for 13.10 or 14.04 also work? Is there any difference? I am trying to get this running on 17.04

Comment: I didn't test but it should work with nothing more than a few small adaptations (if needed). The postfix configuration to use virtual users should be the same (use port 587 instead of 25 of course now). I don't think postfix installation is different now (as it uses apt) but maybe it is good to check with the ubuntu documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postfix.html and adapt the installation if needed.

Comment: On the other hand, that's a personal choice but I would prefer to install postfix and all the server environnement needed to protect it in production on 16.04 because it is a LTS version (and 17.04 isn´t one).